# Is these a way to set the output of printf to a string?

Tags: c++, printf

I need the output of `printf("%02X", buffer[0])` to be put into a string.

In theory it would be something like:

```
string str = printf("%02X", buffer[0]) +printf("%02X", buffer[1]) +printf("%02X", buffer[2]) +printf("%02X", buffer[3]);
```

That, however, doesn't work and i can't figure out how to do it.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: `printf` is a C function, which explains why it mixes so poorly with C++ strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Return value of `printf` is the number of characters written, use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

```
char s[BIG_ENOUGH];

snprintf(s, BIG_ENOUGH, "%02X %02X %02X %02X ", buffer[0],
                                                buffer[1],
                                                buffer[2],
                                                buffer[3]);

std::string str(s);
```

Also, you can forget xprintf ways and use C++ streams:

```
std::ostringstream s;

s << std::hex;

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    s << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << buffer[i] << ' ';

std::string str(s.str());
```

Answer (score 2):

As M M. wrote, sprintf is what you're looking for. Or better yet, use `snprintf` for added security against buffer overflows:

```
char s[SIZE];
snprintf(s, SIZE, "%02X", buffer[0]);
string str(s);
```

snprintf will never write more than SIZE bytes to s.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that boost::format() is a great way to preserve printf() type formatting while outputting to a stream.  Once you are using a stream, you can use std::ostringstream or someting similar to format in memory.